# Advice needed on workflow

Tags: workflow

We are currently trying to decide how to implement workflow into our enterprise application. We must support very complex workflow scenarios and we must also handle approx 10000 concurrent users. The application domain is healthcare. The client is a WPF application talking to an IIS backend using WCF. The question is: Does anybody have any experience with Windows workflow foundation in such a large enterprise application? From the requirements is seems like WWF fits the bill, but I am worried about performance and scalability. Should I continue to investigate into WWF or is WWF just not suitable for this kind of applications? We also need to let our consultants have the ability to alter workflows and re-hosting the WWF designer certainly sounds tempting. What do you think. Is WWF the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a workflow that is directly hosted by IIS. You can use the "Receive" activity to setup the WF to handle requests. You can then attach a "Send" activity to reply back to the client with a response, and even have the workflow continue processing in the background that activity. Hope that provides some direction to get you started. You can achieve this with either the .NET Framework 3.5 or 4.x versions, but .NET 4.0 is much easier to setup.

Answer (score 0):

The performance will rely on the hardware.
Anyway, workflow services  are perfectly scalables in IIS. You will be able to set up a server farm that will serve all the request.

Regarding the requirement of altering workflows, always is possible to alter the workflow in a way that future requests will create instances of the new altered workflow. Old and already initiated workflows can not take any variation. So,if  I have not understood wrongly, WWF does not fit this requirement.